# Infinity norm function in C++

Tags: c++, cygwin

Is there a built in function for the infinity norm in C++? If not, I would like to know which package exactly has it and if it is available for installation using Cygwin. Thanks!

Comment: I think it's called `std::max`.

Comment: I searched for std::max and it needs two parameters and what it only does is return the larger of the two parameters. Hmm, I would like something that takes a vector as an input and then returns the maximum absolute value among the coordinates.

Comment: Sounds like you could use [`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element)

Comment: as suggested by @alterigel https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element

Comment: Yeah max_element, sorry, my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re probably looking for [std::max_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element).